# How to pas array in loop in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I am facing the problem is that I want to display all image by using  array and loop,it is not showing all image  ,it does show only one image.Here is my code

```
if($objResult['Image_Type'] == '01') {
    $img11 = array($objResult['Image_Name']);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($img11[$i]); $i++) {
        $im_mouths = array($img11[$i]);
    }
}
```

here is in the database to extract out all image
[image: in database]

the out put is showing only one image by using this code

```
<?  echo    $im_mouths[0].'11111'.'<br>';?>
<?  echo    $im_mouths[1].'222222'.'<br>';?>
<?  echo    $im_mouths[2].'333333'.'<br>';?>
```

[image: output]

I am not sure I'm doing correctly or not ,help me out this problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: please add code part where you run the query and retrieve the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simplify your code a bit.
Assuming you have a outer loop for retrieving data from database:

```
$im_mouths = array();
while ($objResult = $res->fetch()) {
    if($objResult['Image_Type'] == '01') {
        $im_mouths[] = $objResult['Image_Name'];
    }
}
```

Now you have `$im_mouths` array of elements of image names, as many as you have in database. So as you see you don't need unnecessary inner `for` loop

Finally to see what you have in your `$im_mouths` array, you can `print_r` it:

```
print_r($im_mouths);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only showing one image because you're re-writing `$im_mouths` each time you loop. You should change your loop to do the following:

```
$im_mouths = array();
if($objResult['Image_Type'] == '01') {
    $img11 = array($objResult['Image_Name']);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($img11[$i]); $i++) {
        $im_mouths[] = array($img11[$i]);
    }
}
```

We initialize `$im_mouths` as an array, then add each element to the array  as an element: `$im_mouths[] = ...`.

Comment: Sir ,i get ur point a little ,guide me complete please ,how to add each element to the array as an element:'$im_mouths[]=...'.

Comment: @ThanHtutOo Change it to `$im_mouths[] = $img11[$i];` instead of `$im_mouths[] = array(...)`.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili care to elaborate? I've answered the scope of the question.

Comment: array($objResult['Image_Name']) will always be 1 element array. by this $im_mouths[] = array($img11[$i]); is equal to $im_mouths[] = $img11;

Comment: and I think he wants to have something like this: $im_mouths[] = $objResult['Image_Name'] - adding just image names as array elements not array of arrays

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the variable $im_mouths should contain only the last image ( that is, 20140923jaobangsaen01.png ). Because you are using simple variable to store the image, so that the variable may contain last image while the program flow comes out from the for loop. So that the output of your example is correct. If you want to show each images means, you should use array variable to store all the images and display back to the required place. Rearrange the code like following,

```
$im_mouths = array();
if($objResult['Image_Type'] == '01') {
    $img11 = array($objResult['Image_Name']);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($img11[$i]); $i++) {
        $im_mouths[] = array($img11[$i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it will work fine for you.

Use can use foreach to display the images instead of using echo for each image.

```
$num = 1111;  //if required
foreach ( $im_mouths as $value ) {
    echo $value.$num;
    $num += 1111;
}
```

Comment: sir should i use this '<?  echo    $im_mouths[0].'11111'.'<br>';?>
<?  echo    $im_mouths[1].'222222'.'<br>';?>
<?  echo    $im_mouths[2].'333333'.'<br>';?>'

Comment: I have added a new sample for printing digits